# User input during photoshop script execution (.psd and .jsx files)

Tags: photoshop-script

I have "for" loop which open each .gif file in folder and save them by legacy function "saveForWeb". In the settings window of this type of saving there is a context menu with the ability to optimize the number of colors for the size in KB. The problem is that you cannot call this "optimization" from the script, and if you use "photoshop actions" that it optimizes the color palette for the file that was selected during the recording of the action. Is it possible to somehow leave all automation to pause the script before after opening the SaveForWeb window, manually optimize the color palette based on the size, click "save..." thereby closing the SaveForWeb window and so that the script continues to run.

I think it should be like alert().
When I put an alert() somewhere in the code, when the executed script reaches the alert, everything is paused and continues only after I click on "OK" in  alert().

Comment: Perhaps you should add your code to your post, so others can see what's going on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.